# How do I play video files that are saved on my google drive?

Tags: javascript, api, html5-video

Basically I want to have a small webpage that can search through multiple mp4 files by name that are saved in my google drive.

I have all the files named as such '001.mp4', '002.mp4', '003.mp4'...

The only way I can play them currently is to embed each of them with their ridiculously long urls that are complete gibberish, how can I search for and play these videos based on the file names? I briefly tried to see if I could get an api working but I couldn't understand the google drive instructions for how to do that.